# can not show value in h 1 tag from jquery ajax return data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have html page like this:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "/c1",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".num").eq(0).text(data.recovered_today);
            $(".num").eq(1).text(data.cases_today);
            $(".num").eq(2).text(data.deaths_today);
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1">
        <div class="num" >
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="num" >
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="num">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
  
        <div class="txt">
            <h2>total_cases</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
            <h2>total_recovered</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
            <h2>total_deaths</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

but when I run http://localhost:8088/ it show me like this:
[image]
only text display but numbers are not on the page.
I am sure the data from backend is json format and looks like this:

```
{"recovered_today":23106499,"cases_today":826924,"deaths_today":21311}
```

by the way, the html page has several `<div id="c1">,<div id="c2">`...
root request http://localhost:8088/ will return the html page.
I am new to JavaScript, How can the data be displayed? any idea will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why the JSON you are showing is different than the words in the output you are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're displaying the result in the `<div>`, not the `<h1>`. Add `.find("h1")` to select the nested `<h1>` elements.

It's a good idea to specify `dataType: 'json'` in case the API doesn't send a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/c1",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $(".num").eq(0).find("h1").text(data.cases_today);
    $(".num").eq(1).find("h1").text(data.recovered_today);
    $(".num").eq(2).find("h1").text(data.deaths_today);
  }
})
```